# SelectAll checkbox is not functioning properly when other check-boxes are checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to incorporate the Checkbox functionality in the ng-Grid control.
What my intention is that,

a) Whenever a checkbox is select, the corresponding data should be displayed in a bottom grid. (**achieved**)

b) Whenever the **SelectAll** checkbox will be selected , all the corresponding data should be displayed in a bottom grid. (**achieved**)

c) Whenever a checkbox is unselect, the corresponding data should not displayed in a bottom grid. (**achieved**)

d) Whenever the **SelectAll** checkbox  is unselect , all the corresponding data should not be displayed in a bottom grid. (**achieved**)

**What I could not achieve**

a) If **SelectAll** checkbox is *checked* but any one of the other checkboxes is *unchecked*, then the **SelectAll** *should be unchecked* **(not achieve)**

b) If all the other check-boxes are *checked*, then the **SelectAll** check-box should be *checked* **(not achieve)**

**Sample**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link data-require="ng-grid@2.0.9" data-semver="2.0.9" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.9/ng-grid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
    <script data-require="ng-grid@2.0.9" data-semver="2.0.9" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.9/ng-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
          <div  class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" ></div>
          <div  class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions1" ></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**http://plnkr.co/edit/Yg2AQfx6E0wg1lxwomA6?p=preview**

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry  forgot to post my plunkr here it  is :http://plnkr.co/edit/Yg2AQfx6E0wg1lxwomA6?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there's a typo in your *main.js* file. For the '**cellTemplate**' value of **$scope.columnDefs** the following is mentioned for the input tag:

```
ng-change=\"toggleChecker(COL_FIELD)\"
```

However, later in the script, the following is defined:

```
$scope.toggleCheck = function(checked)
```

When I renamed **toggleCheck** to **toggleChecker**, it seems to be performing both the functionality. Plz check.

Comment: $scope.toggleChecker = function(checker)  i used (checker) instead of(checked) now it works thanking you ......